# C check for number of divisors

Tags: c, division

I am trying to find the number of divisors for each number from 1 to 100, but i do not understand why it is not working. The compiler said that the error is in line 18, 21 and 24.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define N 100

int main()
{
    float n;
    float l

    for (n=1; n<=N; n++) { //genertate a list of numbers
        int a;
        for (a=n; a>=n; a--) { //genarate a list of numbers less than "n"
            l = n/a; //divide each number less than "n" 
            if (l == round(l)) { //see is "l" is a divisor of "n"
                l=l+1; //if it finds a divisor it will add it
                printf(n, l); //prints the number as well as the number of divisors
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the warning that the compiler gave:

```
ks-MacBook-Pro:~ kyle$ gcc /Users/kyle/app-tests/c/divisors.c
/Users/kyle/app-tests/c/divisors.c: In function 'main':
/Users/kyle/app-tests/c/divisors.c:18: error: nested functions are disabled, use -fnested-functions to re-enable
/Users/kyle/app-tests/c/divisors.c:18: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'for'
/Users/kyle/app-tests/c/divisors.c:21: error: 'l' undeclared (first use in this function)
/Users/kyle/app-tests/c/divisors.c:21: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
```

/Users/kyle/app-tests/c/divisors.c:21: error: for each function it appears in.)
/Users/kyle/app-tests/c/divisors.c:24: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of 'printf'

Comment: Lines 21 and 24 don't exist.

Comment: **What** did the compiler say? Did you understand it?

Comment: (You're missing a semicolon after `float l`; that's going to cause problems. Also, why use `float` when `int` will suffice?)

Comment: I recommend using modulus for divisors rather than an integer truncation stored in a float.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
float l
```

Missing the semicolon here

```
printf(n, l);
```

That's not how `printf` is used, use this instead:

```
printf("%f, %f", n, l);
```

This should solve the compile issue.